# Error loading shared library when trying to deploy django using nginx and docker

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, uwsgi

I have been following a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nh1ynJGJuT8) to deploy a django project to docker.  Both docker files work independently but when I run the docker-compose-deploy.yml I get the following error:

```
Attaching to app_1, proxy_1
app_1    |
app_1    | 128 static files copied to '/vol/web/static', 3 unmodified.
app_1    | Error loading shared library libxml2.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bin/uwsgi)
app_1    | Error relocating /usr/local/bin/uwsgi: xmlDocSetRootElement: symbol not found
app_1    | Error relocating /usr/local/bin/uwsgi: xmlCheckVersion: symbol not found
app_1    | Error relocating /usr/local/bin/uwsgi: xmlNewTextChild: symbol not found
app_1    | Error relocating /usr/local/bin/uwsgi: xmlNewChild: symbol not found
app_1    | Error relocating /usr/local/bin/uwsgi: xmlNewDoc: symbol not found
app_1    | Error relocating /usr/local/bin/uwsgi: xmlReadMemory: symbol not found
app_1    | Error relocating /usr/local/bin/uwsgi: xmlNewNode: symbol not found
app_1    | Error relocating /usr/local/bin/uwsgi: xmlDocDumpFormatMemory: symbol not found
app_1    | Error relocating /usr/local/bin/uwsgi: xmlCleanupParser: symbol not found
app_1    | Error relocating /usr/local/bin/uwsgi: xmlFreeDoc: symbol not found
app_1    | Error relocating /usr/local/bin/uwsgi: xmlDocGetRootElement: symbol not found
app_1    | Error relocating /usr/local/bin/uwsgi: xmlGetProp: symbol not found
app_1    | Error relocating /usr/local/bin/uwsgi: xmlFree: symbol not found
proxy_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
proxy_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
proxy_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
app_1 exited with code 127
proxy_1  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
proxy_1  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
proxy_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
proxy_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
proxy_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
proxy_1  | 2021/06/09 10:57:59 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "app" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:9
proxy_1  | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "app" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:9
proxy_1 exited with code 1
```

I tried to add both libxml2 and libxml2-dev to the Dockerfile but it still presents this error.
Here are the dockerfiles and the docker compose:

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services: 
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - static_data:/vol/web
    environment: 
      - SECRET_KEY=samplesecretkey123
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=127.0.0.1,localhost
      
  proxy:
    build:
      context: ./proxy
    volumes: 
      - static_data:/vol/static
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - app

volumes:
  static_data:
```

.Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM python:3.8-alpine

ENV PATH="/scripts:${PATH}"

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp gcc libc-dev linux-headers libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python3-dev gcc build-base libffi-dev
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp

RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./scripts /scripts

RUN chmod +x /scripts/*

RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/media
RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/static

RUN adduser -D user
RUN chown -R user:user /vol
RUN chmod -R 755 /vol/web
USER user

CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

./proxy/Dockerfile

```sh
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1-alpine

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./uwsgi_params /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /vol/static
RUN chmod 755 /vol/static
```

Please let me know if any more information is required.  As I said, the docker files work independently

Answer (score 1):

I changed the app container to use ubuntu rather than alpine and it now works.  libxml2 and alpine has caused me problems in the past too, it just doesn't seem to install properly, for reasons beyond me